# directly copy the folder in webapps of tomcat instead of war

Tags: tomcat, docker

I am trying to see the best practices of deploying a webapp in tomcat. If I try to deploy a war file and containerize it(DCOS Container), it takes almost 50 seconds to deploy may war file. To remove this deployment time, I am thinking of pasting the folder itself instead of war file in webapps folder.

My question is can I simply copy the deployed war file folder instead of asking tomcat to do that for me. Will that even work? or I should not do that and only place war files?

Appreciate help here!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can work, you have to mount the unzipped folder in the same directory. You have to check that tomcat has the auto deloy settings.

I leave you an example that can work for you:

```
your folder:
- api.war
- api //descompresed war file
- docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:7.0.78
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/api
```

If you change the files of that folder tomcat detects them and deploys the application again.